# How to save database with all tables limited with 1000 rows only

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with 20 tables. Currently, we are using the `pg_dump` command daily to archive our database.

a few tables in this database are very big. We are working to make a *light* version of this database for testing purposes and small tickets.

So, I need a way to use `pg_dump` command and save all tables with only 1000 rows in each table. I tried to find anything like that in Google, but without success.

Comment: You will not be able to do that with `pg_dump`. The best you can do is `pg_dump -s ...` where `-s` will dump only the schema definitions and no data. When you did the restore you would have the structure of the database only.  You could set up [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) on the new database back to the original database an do selects  with `LIMIT 1000` to fill the new tables. The tricky part would be maintaining FOREIGN KEY relationships.

Comment: If you are moving data from one database to another, consider the copy command, which *does* allow where clauses

Comment: So, I can create DB schema with pg_dump -s and then use Copy command to copy all tables with 1000 rows in it?? Can you please give me example of the command?

Comment: See the Postgres [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html).

Comment: I see that COPY is working when you need to copy one table to another. But What I should use to copy ALL tables with 1000 rows to another DB?

Comment: You can't do that with `COPY`. You would need to come up with a script that iterates over the tables and pulls data from each.